# Read XML using VBA: List all occurrences of a tag including contextRef

Tags: xml, vba, edgar

I'm new to VBA and XML and would appreciate your help. I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub XMLfromPPTExample()
Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objxmlnodexbrl As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim objXMLNodeDIIRSP As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/936468/000119312516476010/lmt-20151231.xml")
Set objxmlnodexbrl = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("xbrl")
Set objXMLNodeDIIRSP = objxmlnodexbrl.SelectSingleNode("us-gaap:GrossProfit")
Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value = objXMLNodeDIIRSP.Text
End Sub
```

This accesses a specific XML-sheet on SEC's Edgar database and writes the value of a defined tag ("us-gaap:GrossProfit") into Excel field A1.

However, it is possible that this tag occurs several times in this XML-file with different values. What I need is that each of these occurrences are printed into an excel table, including the value and the value of "contextRef".

Could you please adapt my code so that this works? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using MSXML DOM's [XPath](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288913), making sure to declare the namespace `us:gaap`. Below iterates by node index `[#]` of each `<us-gaap:grossProfit>` tag:

```vb
Sub XMLfromPPTExample()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objxmlnodexbrl As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim grossProfitList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim XmlNamespaces As String
    Dim row As Integer

    Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.Load ("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/936468/000119312516476010/lmt-20151231.xml")

    XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:us-gaap='http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2015-01-31'"
    XDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces
    XDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

    Set grossProfitList = XDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//us-gaap:GrossProfit")

    For row = 1 To grossProfitList.Length
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & row).Value = XDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//us-gaap:GrossProfit[" & row & "]")(0).Text
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & row).Value = XDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//us-gaap:GrossProfit[" & row & "]/@contextRef")(0).Text
    Next row

    Set grossProfitList = Nothing
    Set XDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
4187000000  eol_PE11373---1510-K0017_STD_365_20131231_0
5255000000  eol_PE11373---1510-K0017_STD_365_20141231_0
5200000000  eol_PE11373---1510-K0017_STD_365_20151231_0
```